# JAVAMETHOD grok pattern with optional thread number at the end

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I'm trying to parse log4j messages:

```
2019-12-02 20:48:20.198utc DEBUG UnknownElementContentHandler,streamLock-9-th-11:32 - blabla
2019-11-19 23:40:04.014utc  WARN AnnotationBinder,localhost-startStop-1:611 - blabla
2019-11-19 23:40:04.014utc  INFO CovImCtl,main:109 - blabla
```

with grok pattern

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}utc%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{JAVACLASS:class},%{JAVAMETHOD1:method}:%{POSINT:lineno}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}
with using a variation on the standard:
JAVAMETHOD (?:(<(?:cl)?init>)|[a-zA-Z$_][a-zA-Z$_0-9]*)
JAVAMETHOD1 (?:(<(?:cl)?init>)|[a-zA-Z$_][a-zA-Z$_\-0-9]*)
```

The JAVAMETHOD worked for "main" but not for the others, (the pattern was missing -).
JAVAMETHOD1 works, but I need to get the **optional** trailing integer retrieved as a "thread_no" field (11 from streamLock-9-th-11, 1 from localhost-startStop-1)

I'm wrecking my brain, the methods like streamLock-9-th-11 has the internal "-\d+" "-9" which belongs to "streamLock-9-th"

Any ideas?